# netctl: multiple Wifi APs with same SSID

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, netctl

Yesterday I travelled by train and there were multiple Wifi APs with the same SSID. I had no problem connecting to the Wifi; I'm just curios how netctl handles
such a case. Which of the available APs will it connect to, and does it seamlessly switch between the available APs if one of them gets out of range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in such cases bridges are used to interconnect up multiple access points on the same network or else signal repeaters, also known as expanders signal.